# Animation missing while Sheet in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

For few screen when I present the sheet below view comes little down with some transition effect and width get shrink, I guess its default behaviour of sheet, but when I push to other view and try to present sheet from there I am not getting that effect, even though the code syntax is same. Is there any way to achieve that animation

[image]

```
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPopView) {
                    DetailsView(
                        viewModel: viewModel.detailsViewModel
                    )
                }
```

for ex. Transition showed in this link
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-new-view-using-sheets